# How to find Max Speed ever achieved by Cars?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

In NFS Mostwanted i want to know the **max speed** ever achieved by some car.

we can know for races as they maintain max speed details but i want to know for **lifetime** max speed achieved.

By the word **life time** means that particular car have **ever achieved** its maximum speed, either **in race** or **in Cops chase**  or **in Bounty gain** or **in pursuit**

---

### Example :

I've seen Max speed of `Lamborgini Gallardo` **374 Km/h** on record in race but i have achieved more of it some thing above **385** in `bounty` and also i want to compare with other cars max speed

Is there any way to get it,
any plugin<
crack or any hack???????????????

Comment: can any one still answer this for newer versions of NFS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no way to find your maximum speed ever achieved.

However, if you think you've crossed your maximum speed in a race, you could check the speed at the Statistics page when you have finished the race.

Comment: @Photon It answers the question very directly. It says that what you want is not possible within the game.